# Google says no structured data exists when content only shows up with user interaction

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I have a website and I am working over its SEO. I have put all required structured data in it as per my knowledge and have also tested it with Google Webmaster's Structured Data Testing Tool and it detects everything fine and all requirements are met.

But back in *Webmasters Tools* when I go to: Search Appearances > Structured Data it says:

```
We do not detect any structured data on your site.
Structured data helps Google understand the content on your site, which can be used to display rich snippets in search results.
```

Why is this happening, and do you have any idea how I can correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Google cannot match the content of your page(s) to your structured data.

When I test your website URL in the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), it's displaying this:

> Error: The information will not appear as a rich snippet in search results, because the marked-up content does not appear to be the main focus of the page.

Looking at your website, it appears that the content is heavily stylized. Also, you have [makesOffer](https://schema.org/makesOffer) specified twice...

I would take another look at your structured data, and make sure that Google will be able to see matching content in your page(s).

Comment: but that Error is only for a particular part? is Google going to reject the whole markup because of this? plus can you explain a bit about `heavily stylized`?

Comment: Yes, errors are not warnings and should not be ignored. There is only one sentence currently visible on your site (without mouse movement) - content can't be hidden from the user (or Google). See number 3 and the others [here](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets).

Comment: thats means i cant have the luxury of such hiding/showing element effects in site if i want to keep it optimized, its true right? and would it be foolish to ask for an alternative?

Comment: Correct, hiding content may also impact your SEO performance so you should use it sparingly. By alternative, if you mean to show one site to users and another to Google, that's referred to as [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and could result in penalties.

Comment: Thank you, i think i wouldn't take the risk with cloaking and instead would think of changing those effects on the site.

Comment: You're welcome - sounds good.