# Structured data and visible content revisited

Tags: seo, microdata, markup, semantic-web, structured-data

Structured data (like schema.org markup) should traditionally be used on visible content (a search on here will confirm that) and Google and others have said as much.

However, [schema.org is now supporting JSON](http://blog.schema.org/2013/06/schemaorg-and-json-ld.html) which would never be visible on-page. Additionally, and for quite some time, the [Good Relations Snippet Generator](http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/grsnippetgen/) has created snippets that are empty divs with instructions to post it before the closing `<body>` tag of your webpages.

Does anyone have practical experience (even better, A/B testing) of the results (or problems) from using Semantic Web markup on visible vs. non-visible content or any insight/guidelines?

Comment: Semantic markup/annotations can be consumed by a variety of agents. As you tagged your question with [tag:seo], are you interested in search engines *only*?

Comment: Mainly, yes. I work in SEO and marketing and so while I'd consider other potential uses that would definitely be my primary concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions for the [Good Relations on-line snippet generator tool](http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/grsnippetgen/) only states to [update the XHTML/HTML page header](http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/grsnippetgen/#mod_header), and their [Quickstart](http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Quickstart) guide states for each example to:

> Insert the additional HTML markup given below anywhere **in the body section**...

I do not see instructions to "post it *before* the closing `<body>` tag of your webpages."

Also, the [schema blog on JSON-LD](http://blog.schema.org/2013/06/schemaorg-and-json-ld.html) only states:

> W3C's work on JSON-LD provides mechanisms for interpreting structured
>   data in JSON that promotes interoperability with other data formats.
>   We believe it provides value for developers and publishers, and
>   improves the flow of information between JSON and other environments.

So these do not support using Semantic Web markup in non-visible content as far as SEO is concerned.

Comment: I think they updated the Good Relations instructions but I think it used to say the part I quoted...oh well, it's pretty clear now. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. It should be visible, with matching content, or you'll likely have a problem, like [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53541/google-says-no-structured-data-exists-but-it-does/53542#53542) question.