# How to update the date on Google search results?

Tags: google-search, googlebot, search-results, meta-tags

For a blog entry, I have this meta tags:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2015-09-07T21:54:43+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2015-11-13T13:28:21+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2015-11-13T13:28:21+00:00" />
```

However, Google only shows the published time on the search results (2015-09-07). I want it to show the last modified time (2015-11-13). **What do I need to add in order to achieve this?**

I compare my site with others like WPBeginner in which Google shows the updated time. The only difference in the HTML code is this meta tag:

```
<meta name="revised" content="Tuesday, October 20, 2015, 10:05 am" />
```

Nevertheless, I added this last meta tag to my site too but nothing happened.

Also, my XML sitemap includes `<lastmod>` information.

Comment: How long ago did you add the tag?  Search results can take a while to update.

Comment: Can take months to update meta markup.

Comment: The first 3 meta tags are automatically added since September, and I made several changes in between but the date was never updated by Google. I added the last one ("revised") on 13 November, but I don't think Google sees that meta tag.

Comment: Well your first mistake is comparing your site to another with Google updates. Google has limited resources and favours popular sites, for instant it's estimated that WPBeginner has over 6M visitors each month, unless your site has this many visitors, or the links they have then its extremely unlikely your get updates quickly. Depending on your volume of pages will also have an impact, so if Google considers you not so important, and you have thousands of pages then your going to have to wait a awful a lot of time for page updates, such as meta changes, titles and so forth.

Comment: Google does however learn, so the more you update those pages the more regularly it'll check back, but to assume its not updating comparing to another site, is just bad practice. You should verify your code, and if its fine... then Google will update it, just need to wait and work on your domain authorithy.

Comment: @SimonHayter thanks for expand your reply. Actually, I've seen updates on titles and descriptions on my pages. I only compared my site with another to see if I was missing something in the HTML. However, my real question would be if what I have is enough. I really don't know what is used by Google to update dates and I couldn't find anything about this on the Internet.

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess here... update your HTTP headers so the last modified date is accurate, and submit the sitemap for the page and include the accurate date for the URL in the sitemap as well

Comment: @Mike I just checked with Google Webmaster Tools and "Last-Modified" HTTP header has today's date (30m ago). Also, the sitemap was automatically processed on 19 November, according to the Sitemaps section.

Comment: @SimonHayter I finally found the solution and Google update the date in less than 12 hours (maybe less, but I was sleeping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78588/when-does-google-use-article-published-date-vs-article-modified-date-in-serp) is to **only have one date visible**. Thus, the published date should not be visible and the modified date should be the one in the article.

[Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59559/how-to-tell-how-old-a-page-is/59566#59566) there is a good research, and mentions:

> It is known that Google looks specifically for a date just under the first H1 tag. This is because blogs often put dates in this location.

**After I made this change, Google showed the last modified time** (in less than 12 hours).